# Warning for Versioned Core Data Model with Custom Value Transformer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

In my app, I have a Core Data model that contains entities that have properties with transformed values that use a custom `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` I've defined. For example, from [Apple's sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/handling_different_data_types_in_core_data):

```swift
class ColorToDataTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
    
    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return UIColor.self
    }
    
    override class var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [UIColor.self]
    }

    override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let data = value as? Data else {
            fatalError("Wrong data type: value must be a Data object; received \(type(of: value))")
        }
        return super.transformedValue(data)
    }
    
    override func reverseTransformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any? {
        guard let color = value as? UIColor else {
            fatalError("Wrong data type: value must be a UIColor object; received \(type(of: value))")
        }
        return super.reverseTransformedValue(color)
    }
}

extension NSValueTransformerName {
    static let colorToDataTransformer = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: "ColorToDataTransformer")
}
```

This is included over in the data model as a property's transformer:

[image: Screenshot of the attribute editor in Xcode, showing a property whose type is transformable, with its transformer set to ColorToDataTransformer]

However, when I add a new model version by selecting `Editor > Add Model Version…`, a warning appears that says:

```
no NSValueTransformer with class name 'ColorToDataTransformer' was found for attribute 'tintColor' on entity 'Book'
```

This is a compile-time warning, and not a runtime console log as I've seen references to that message being in the past

This is despite making no other code changes. How would I correct my code/model so the warning goes away? Note that I've already tried each of:

- Setting the `Module` on the attribute to `Current Product Module`
- Defining `ColorToDataTransformer` with `@objc(ColorToDataTransformer)`
- Setting `Suppress all momc warnings` build setting to `Yes`

None of those made the warning go away, however. I'm currently working on an app that targets iOS 16.4 and using Xcode 15.0.1 (15A507)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've just been living with the warning. I filed FB13297759 back in October if you'd like to file a duplicate